# Observer checkout cart update not working

Tags: magento

it's my first post on this page, so please don't hit me too much :)
I want to have too events for checkout. One of them works fine, but other doesn't. I don't know what's wrong in my code. Please help.

Event checkout_cart_product_add_after - works good, but checkout_cart_update_items_after - doesn't work.

config.xml

```
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <tim_checkout_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Tim_Checkout_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>applyTotalPrice</method>
                </tim_checkout_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
        <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
            <observers>
                <tim_checkout_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Tim_Checkout_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>applyTotalPrices</method>
                </tim_checkout_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
    </events>
```

Tim_Checkout_Model_Observer

```
public function applyTotalPrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }
    if(Mage::helper('checkout/calculator')->isBarrelProduct($item->getProduct())){
        $specialPrice = Mage::helper('checkout/calculator')->getProductWorth($item->getProduct());
        if ($specialPrice > 0) {
            $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
    }

}

public function applyTotalPrices(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    foreach ($observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getParentItem()) {
            $item = $item->getParentItem();
        }
        if(Mage::helper('checkout/calculator')->isBarrelProduct($item->getProduct())){
            $specialPrice = Mage::helper('checkout/calculator')->getProductWorth($item->getProduct());
            if ($specialPrice > 0) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think there is not running applyTotalPrices method, but I don't know how to debug observers?

Answer (score 0):

First i would put a Mage::log() at the begin of the observer to review if the function runs when then events occurs